# Custom icon overlays for namespace extension

Tags: windows, com, atl, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I'm implementing the namespace extension which represents the remote file system on the server and I would like to have the icon overlays to show the file state (locked) like in another question here: [icon overlay handlers for namespace extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20975679/3713788)

That question is answered already there and I've done everything as suggested:

1. Created the additional shell extension with the IShellIconOverlayIdentifier interface implemented:
   In the IShellIconOverlayIdentifier.GetOverlayInfo I return icon file and icon index.
   In the IShellIconOverlayIdentifier.IsMemberOf I return S_FALSE to not show my overlay for any other files in the system.
2. In the main NSE I've implemented the IShellIconOverlay interface and retrieve my icon overlay from the system image list using the SHGetIconOverlayIndex function.

The problem is: SHGetIconOverlayIndex always returns -1.

But! If I return S_OK as the result of IShellIconOverlayIdentifier.IsMemberOf - the SHGetIconOverlayIndex immediately starts to give the correct overlay index! But of course in this case my overlay is added to all the files in the system including my NSE.

The interesting thing that if I return S_FALSE in the subesequent calls of the IShellIconOverlayIdentifier.IsMemberOf - the SHGetIconOverlayIndex still give the correct overlay index the everything became fine: I have overlays in my NSE only...

What I'm doing wrong and how to get this result from the very beginning? Probably the caching issue?..

(Sorry, I couldn't write this as the comment to question being mentioned because I have no enough reputation...)

Comment: How many icon handlers are registered in your system?

Comment: I mean overlay icon handlers.

Comment: @Denis, you are genius! Yes, there are more than 15 in my dev system, so I put the "000" characters at the beginning of the name in the registry to place it higher.
Just tried it on another system with only 4 non-system overlay handlers registered - it loads my icon from the beginning! How can I get this result on the first system? Reset some shell icon cache?..

Comment: Tried to call FileIconInit(TRUE) on the NSE dll attach - does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks the problem you have has no correct solution. Maybe I wrong but I think Windows work with using of the following rules:

1) At the start shell has overlay icon list containing default overlay icons only (4 icons, in next version of Windows this value can be larger).

2) When any of overlay icon handlers return S_OK in call of IShellIconOverlayIdentifier.IsMemberOf shell adds its icon to overlay icon list.

3) The max count of overlay icon in shell icon list is 15 (4 default + 11 external).

4) So only 11 first icon handlers returning S_OK will be added to shell icon list. Other will be ingnored.

So even if you rename your registry key to 000 other icon handlers may return S_OK before your handler.

So my recommendation is create full icon with overlay image for your NSE objects.

Comment: Finally I've got the tricky solution based on your "rules":
When the SHGetIconOverlayIndex returns -1 in my NSE I call the SHGetFileInfo function passing some unique file name and SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_ADDOVERLAYS flags.
This causes the call of my IShellIconOverlayIdentifier.IsMemberOf where I check that unique file name and return S_OK.
All this works like the preloading of my icon overlay so that the subsequent calls of SHGetIconOverlayIndex works fine :)))
Thank you for pointing me to the right direction!

Comment: To preload icon you can also try to use function SHLoadNonloadedIconOverlayIdentifiers.

Comment: Tried SHLoadNonloadedIconOverlayIdentifiers, but it did not work in my case. I think it still needs the successfull invocation of IShellIconOverlayIdentifier.IsMemberOf at least once.

Comment: @Alexey hi Alexey, i'm facing the same problem - i didnt undrestnad if your IsMemberOf always return false? i need the icons only in my namespace extension

Comment: @ArielB, in the simple case if there are less than 15 overlay icons in the system - yes, IsMemberOf always returns S_FALSE, because it never called for the virtual items of my NSE. So I return the overlay index to the shell via the IShellIconOverlay interface of my NSE.

Comment: @Alexey yep, i have no problem about the 15 limitation, as i will assure it will always be the topmost. 2 more questions:
1 - About the NSE part - you return the path of the actual file? and question 2 - can you create several icons in the same IShellIconOverlayIdentifier? i don't want to create dll per icon

Comment: @ArielB You cannot assign several overlay icons to single IShellIconOverlayIdentifier handler. But you can create a dll with several IShellIconOverlayIdentifier handlers inside. And you can combine your IShellIconOverlayIdentifier handlers and your NSE in single dll.

Comment: @DenisAnisimov hm, i'll try that  :) hope i won't need more follow ups. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, i would love to get some directions, i can't get it to work..
i've installed it under the CLSID + first place in the list.
the extension is not called, what am i missing?

Comment: @ArielB Reboot or restart Explorer?

Comment: Ok, finally, after long hours, i managed to get it working - Thank you @Alexey for your help.
i have 1 more question:
1. it seems that when i call to SHGetFileInfo - the file must exist, so i have to create a dummy file - is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @ArielB I know it may no longer be relevant, but for the world's future reference: if you call SHGetFileInfo with SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES, then the file does not have to exist. I've tested this successfully on Windows 10.