# windows shell extension Overlay can not show

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

everyone,
I use Flickr drive shell extension（ https://www.viksoe.dk/code/flickrdrive.htm )
Go to write a cloud disk and find that the overlay extension and the tree on the left cannot be displayed normally. Overlay extension can be normally displayed on other local disks, but the folder in the cloud disk cannot be displayed. The secondary directory in the tree on the left side of the Explorer can be displayed, but the directory below the secondary level cannot be displayed.
As shown in the figure, now I want to ask how to solve it!

```
#pragma once

class CShellFolder;

class ATL_NO_VTABLE COverlayIcon:
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<COverlayIcon, &CLSID_OverlayIcon>,
    //public IDispatchImpl<IMyOverlayIcon, &IID_IMyOverlayIcon, &LIBID_OverlayIconLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
    public IShellIconOverlayIdentifier
{
public: 

    //DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_MYOVERLAYICON)
    CRefPtr<CShellFolder> m_spFolder;
    CComPtr<IDataObject> m_spDataObject;    
    CPidl m_pidlItem;
    bool m_bAcceptFmt;

    BEGIN_COM_MAP(COverlayIcon)
        //COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IShellIconOverlayIdentifier)
    END_COM_MAP()


    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    static HRESULT WINAPI UpdateRegistry(BOOL bRegister) throw();

    HRESULT Init(CShellFolder* pFolder, PCUITEMID_CHILD pidlItem, HWND hWnd);

    //STDMETHOD(IsMemberOf)(THIS_ _In_ PCWSTR pwszPath, DWORD dwAttrib);
    //STDMETHOD(GetOverlayInfo)(THIS_ _Out_writes_(cchMax) PWSTR pwszIconFile, int cchMax, _Out_ int * pIndex, _Out_ DWORD * pdwFlags) PURE;
    //STDMETHOD(GetPriority)(THIS_ _Out_ int * pIPriority) PURE;

    // IShellIconOverlayIdentifier Methods
    STDMETHOD(GetOverlayInfo)(LPWSTR pwszIconFile, int cchMax, int *pIndex, DWORD* pdwFlags);
    STDMETHOD(GetPriority)(int* pPriority);
    STDMETHOD(IsMemberOf)(LPCWSTR pwszPath, DWORD dwAttrib);    

};
```

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "OverlayIcon.h"
#include "ShellFolder.h"

STDMETHODIMP COverlayIcon::GetOverlayInfo(
    LPWSTR pwszIconFile,
    int cchMax, int* pIndex,
    DWORD* pdwFlags)
{
    //GetModuleFileNameW(_AtlBaseModule.GetModuleInstance(), pwszIconFile, cchMax);
    pwszIconFile = _T("c:\\test.ico");  

    *pIndex = 1;
    *pdwFlags = ISIOI_ICONFILE;// | ISIOI_ICONINDEX;
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("ss"), _T("sdf"),MB_OK);
    return S_OK;
}

// IShellIconOverlayIdentifier Method Implementation 

// returns the priority of this overlay 0 being the highest. 
// this overlay is always selected do to its high priority 
STDMETHODIMP COverlayIcon::GetPriority(int* pPriority)
{
    // highest priority
    *pPriority = 0;
    return S_OK;
}

// IShellIconOverlayIdentifier Method Implementation
// IShellIconOverlayIdentifier::IsMemberOf
// Returns Whether the object should have this overlay or not 
STDMETHODIMP COverlayIcon::IsMemberOf(LPCWSTR pwszPath, DWORD dwAttrib)
{
    //wchar_t *s = _wcsdup(pwszPath);
    HRESULT r = S_OK;

    //_wcslwr(s);

    //// Criteria
    //if (wcsstr(s, L"codeproject") != 0)
    //  r = S_OK;

    //free(s);

    return r;
}

HRESULT WINAPI COverlayIcon::UpdateRegistry(BOOL bRegister) throw()
{
    // COM registration is done by CShellFolder instance
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT COverlayIcon::Init(CShellFolder* pFolder, PCUITEMID_CHILD pidlItem, HWND hWnd)
{
    ATLTRACE(L"CDropTarget::Init\n");
    ATLASSERT(m_spFolder == NULL);  
    m_spFolder = pFolder;
    m_pidlItem = pidlItem;
    return S_OK;
}

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(CLSID_OverlayIcon, COverlayIcon)
```

[OverlayIcon can show on local disk][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/762Zd.png
[OverlayIcon can not show on cloud disk][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct2as.png
[the secondary directory cannot be displayed, and the directory below the third level cannot be displayed][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJspt.png

Comment: There are different questions. For folders at any level, check the official Microsoft sample as it demonstrates that: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/shellextensibility/explorerdataprovider For overlays, implement IShellIconOverlay, not IShellIconOverlayIdentifier

Comment: I want to use a custom overlay Icon. What should I do.

Comment: implement IShellIconOverlay in your shell folder or add another specific shell extension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975679/icon-overlay-handlers-for-namespace-extension